# sed complains on numbers in bash script

Tags: bash, sed, sh

I'm writing a script to replace dafault configuration values to user specified ones. But i'm getting unterminated 's' command errors from sed. After 2 Hours of googling i still haven't figured out whats causing this. The lines are:

```
CONFIG_GMETAD_COMPUTENODES="scccompute1 scccompute2"
CONFIG_GMETAD="/etc/gmetad.conf"
sed -i 's/localhost/'${CONFIG_GMETAD_COMPUTENODES}'/g' ${CONFIG_GMETAD}
```

this substitutes to

```
sed -i 's/localhost/scccompute1 scccompute2/g' /etc/gmetad.conf
```

error i get

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command
```

I don't see whats wrong in here, but haven't worked quite often with sed.

Comment: sed -i "s/localhost/${CONFIG_GMETAD_COMPUTENODES}/g" ${CONFIG_GMETAD}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote your variables.  Note how the `sed` command expands:

```
sed -i 's/localhost/'scccompute1 scccompute2'/g' /etc/gmetad.conf
```

This creates multiple options, not a single one with your sed script.  Instead, try:

```
sed -i 's/localhost/'"${CONFIG_GMETAD_COMPUTENODES}"'/g' "${CONFIG_GMETAD}"
```

Containing the variable within double quotes causes the whole string to be treated as a single argument to `sed`, which is what you want. And of course, quotes around the filename because the filename might contain special characters.  As a rule, always quote variables when you refer to them in bash.

Note that if the embedded variable contains slashes or some other special characters, it may break your script.  So you might want to do some sanity checking before feeding it to `sed`:

```
CONFIG_GMETAD_COMPUTENODES="${CONFIG_GMETAD_COMPUTENODES//[^a-z0-9 ]/}"
```

This will strip all characters that are not alphanumeric or space, if bash is your shell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from quoting in bash.

You should use

`sed -i "s/localhost/${CONFIG_GMETAD_COMPUTENODES}/g"`